# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, py2exe

I have created a python application using py2exe. when i run this exe/application on my build environment, it works properly. But when i try to run it on clean machine, it gives me a error that,

```
                   Traceback (most recent call last):
                   File "wx\_misc.pyc", line 1358, in Notify
                   File "wx\_core.pyc", line 14771, in Notify
                   File "invesalius.py", line 174, in Startup
                   File "gui\frame.pyc", line 30, in <module>
                   File "constants.pyc", line 25, in <module>
                   File "project.pyc", line 31, in <module>
                   File "vtk\__init__.pyc", line 43, in <module>
                   File "vtkIOPython.pyc", line 12, in <module>
                   File "vtkIOPython.pyc", line 10, in __load
                   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be                   
                                found.
                    Traceback (most recent call last):
                    File "wx\_misc.pyc", line 1358, in Notify
                    File "wx\_core.pyc", line 14771, in Notify
                    File "invesalius.py", line 82, in Startup2
                    AttributeError: 'SplashScreen' object has no attribute 'control'
                    Traceback (most recent call last):
                    File "invesalius.py", line 197, in OnClose
                    AttributeError: 'SplashScreen' object has no attribute 'fc'
```

I am using:
1. windows 8.1 RTM(64 bit)
2. python (2.7 amd64)
3. py2exe (0.6.10a1)

Any comments will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a python runtime on the target machine. Does the error message give you any more information about the missing DLL? If there is no further information, there is a Dependency Walker program (depends.exe) that may help you identify the missing dll.

Comment: Thanks Choi for reply, i have a python runtime environment on target machine and i have checked all dll's and exe in dependency walker too.. but hard luck..this walker shows some windows dlls error. i have provided that dlls too...but didn't work. and it doesn't give any error message specific to dll.

Comment: I presume your PATH is set up correctly, so that they newly added DLLs show up in dependency walker. If that's the case, it might be that Python is loading the DLL explicitly. In that case, I would be tempted to use something like strace to figure out which files it is trying to load.